# apply SSR (Server Side Rendering) just in one or 2 components using React and Razzle

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, csr

I want to apply SSR on my React project, after much research on It, I decide to use Razzle with React.
Now I want to know how can I applying SSR just to some components and other ones stay as normal React CSR (Client Side Rendering) component?

Comment: There was a similar question on [GitHub](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/issues/431), maybe you can have a look into it.